# Get list of address suggested by GoogleMaps AutoComplete HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have already successfully implemented the 'place_changed' event in order to get notified when the user selects an adress. That's not what I'm looking  for.

I need to get the list of addresses that appear bellow the input box. Is that possible? Is there any other event I'm missing?

**EDIT**

It looks like I there's no way to get the list of addresses suggested in the input box, so I need to implement something based on this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list(the suggestions for a given query) may be requested via the [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service).

But note: you'll get only the predictions and place_id's, to get more details you must request them on your own via a [Place Detail Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details).

But when you really want to get the predictions which appear under a Autocomplete: there is no API-based access, you'll need to parse the DOMNode to get some informations(`.pac-container`)